# Efficient way to extract columns from row matrix in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have a GraphX graph where each vertex holds a portion of the coefficients of a huge matrix (in a matrix which contains a narrow matrix).

On node 1:

```
[a11 a12 a13, ...]
[a21 a22 a23, ...]
[a31 a32 a33, ...]
```

On node 2:

```
[a41 a42 a43, ...]
[a51 a52 a53, ...]
[a61 a62 a63, ...]
```

What I need is to efficiently join those matrices in a way that I can retrieve columns. So I could get a vector

```
v2 = [a12,a22,a32,a42,a52,a62,...]
```

Comment: Could you add more details i.e code and data (input and expected output) ?

Comment: Added the details.